# Unable to create a table in existing wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a table in existing wordpress database and I am unable to create it. I have write this code inside a custom plugin files. Please help me through this code.

```
function create_xml_table(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tableName = $wpdb->prefix."XMLdata";
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName(id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                post_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                value varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                time timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY  (id)
            ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_xml_table');
}
```

Comment: Please try adding the following after your dbDelta call

global $EZSQL_ERROR;

var_dump($EZSQL_ERROR);

What does the var_dump show?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this.

```
function create_xml_table(){

global $wpdb;
$tableName = $wpdb->prefix."XMLdata";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName(id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                            user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                            post_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                            value varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                            time timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
                            )$charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_xml_table');
```

Comment: Close your function before the register_activation_hook()

Comment: Please can u  explain me what's the difference between my code and this one?

Comment: Yes you have close your function after register_activation_hook() instead of before i have already explain you .

Comment: thanks for answering me.... but still i am unable to see the table in wordpress database . Even it's not displaying any error by which i recognize my error. Please help me to get this.

Comment: Try this link https://pippinsplugins.com/create-database-tables-when-plugin-is-activated/

Comment: I have tried this link but this is similar to the previous one.and i am struggling for this for a long while.can u tell me what's the actual problrm is here?